# Add python pdfkit module to setup.py dependencies

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection, pip, dependency-management

Im creating a django app that uses pdfkit module. I've followed django's official site tutorial on how to package my app so it would be available via pip install, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app).

my `setup.py`:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as readme:
    README = readme.read()

# allow setup.py to be run from any path
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

setup(
    name='django-custom-report',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['custom_report'],
    include_package_data=True,
    license='BSD License',  # example license
    description='A simple Django app to custom reports at admin interface '\
    'based on your models.',
    long_description=README,
    url='http://www.example.com/',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='myemail@mysite.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License', # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        # Replace these appropriately if you are stuck on Python 2.
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'django>=1.7',
        'pdfkit',
    ]
)
```

Problem is, on my install_requires I can't simply add pdfkit because it needs a system dependency which is installed through apt-get, as follows the docs of pdfkit [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit).

So, question is:
How can I add a dependency on my setup.py which requires another dependency only installed via apt-get? (e.g.: `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`)

Comment: `pip` will only handle pythonic dependencies for you. Yet you can manually check for `wkhtmltopdf` in `setup.py` and raise an exception with an appropriate error message for the user.